# JSONLint Failed Validation

Tags: json, validation, google-maps-api-3, jsonlint

I'm plotting out some points in Google Maps, however some of the JSON isn't populating correctly. Flipping through a few of the points, i noticed that the default image wasn't populating. Chrome inspector shows that the value of the `src` attribute in img's that aren't working is undefined. when i run the JSON through JSONlint, it's throwing an error on a string:

> "Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['";

It says that it's not, when it is. i'm sure i borked something else up and that's why it's not showing up as a string, but what? Not sure how to go forward testing this. You can check out the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/4Y3JF/

Answer (score 0):

I don't get a JSON-validation-error, but not all items of the JSON have a length of  **9**, so accessing `locations[i][8]` will fail there.

There are also items with a length of 10, the img-src there can be found in `locations[i][9]`

You may access the img-src by using the index of the last entry:

```
locations[i][locations[i].length-1]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Y3JF/2/

Comment: did you use jsonlint to validate? i see an error on line 96. i figured i may have omitted a few values and maybe that was throwing it off...how could you tell the items have different lengths? your solution works, but i'd rather ensure data quality before i used. thanks man

Comment: I've been using http://jsonlint.com/ for validation .  After that I was using PHP to decode the JSON and I saw that there are items with a length of 8,9 and 10